# Most developed magit/github extension for emacs for pull requests

Tags: git, emacs, github, magit

I'm specifically interested in pull requests, editing issues and tying them to commits, and other things I generally have to use [hub on the command line](https://github.com/github/hub) for.  However, I've started using magit and really like the keybindings and general interface---I'd like to stay in emacs for this part, too, rather than needing to keep an extra shell open for pull requests, issues, etc.

The packages that might add the most github functionality to magit that I could find are:

- [Magithub](https://github.com/nex3/magithub)
- [magit-gh-pulls](https://github.com/sigma/magit-gh-pulls)
- [gh.el](https://github.com/sigma/gh.el)

Can anyone, possibly involved with these projects, recommend how they'd compare and what might be best for integrating pull requests into a magit environment?

Comment: You can create custom functions that use `call-process` and `set-process-sentinel` and shell-out behind the scenes so that you never feel like you are leaving the current buffer -- the libraries you mentioned are shelling-out anyway.  If the function you want doesn't exist, then just create it like the unrelated function in the following link (which pushes to multiple repositories):  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23178396/2112489

Comment: Editors always close questions asking for recommendations, but I want to cite the answer I got here again as a perfect example of why asking for software recommendations can be an awesome thing and totally in line with SO objectives if done right.  The developer of the package offered an excellent comparison of the options and their histories---that is /exactly/ what I needed and why it's fantastically useful!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Eventually I will implement such things in Magit (I am the maintainer), but I first have to get a release out.

**Old outdated information:** Unfortunately there currently also isn't a third-party extensions that could fill this role. `magithub` has been broken for a long time now. `magit-gh-pulls` (by Yann, my predecessor as Magit maintainer) also wasn't kept in sync with the changes in Magit. I tried to fix it up some time ago, but gave up when it became clear that doing so would result in a complete rewrite . `gh.el` is also written by Yann and is used by `magit-gh-pulls`. I have contributed to it in the past but eventually stopped using it because (a) it uses `url.el` and that turned out to be very unreliable (b) it's over complex.

So I am afraid there currently isn't a package that does what you want. If you want to write it yourself, I recommend you use `request.el` and then only implement those parts of the Github api that you actually need, to avoid over-engineering it.

**Edit: As of October 2015** `magit-gh-pulls` is [maintained](https://github.com/sigma/magit-gh-pulls) again, but no longer an official extension. Personally I don't use it, as I think it should either to more or less. I currently use "less" in the form of `magit-branch-pull-request` from the [`magit-rockstar`](https://github.com/tarsius/magit-rockstar) library. Even though I maintain that library, I do not consider it an official extension - it's provided as-is. That function is very basic, you give it an issue number and it creates a branch for you, that's it.

**Edit in September 2016:** I have written [`ghub.el`](https://github.com/tarsius/ghub) and [`glab.el`](https://gitlab.com/tarsius/glab) as replacements for `gh.el`. They are mostly intended for my own personal use and provide *very* little, basically they give you functions such as `ghub-get (resource &optional params data noerror)`, you then have to look at the respective api documentation to figure out what `resource`, `params`, and `data` you have to use. Also the error handling isn't great and this currently uses `url.el`. I intend to improve both eventually by using `libcurl` some time after an Emacs with ffi support has been released.

**Edit in January 2020:** More than a year ago I have [released `forge`](https://emacsair.me/2018/12/19/forge-0.1/).

> Forge allows you to work with Git forges—such as Github and Gitlab—from the comfort of Magit and the rest of Emacs.

Comment: Any further thoughts on this, nearly a year later? I just saw that atom has a plugin for some nice looking support to view github pull request comments inline in the editor, which would be beautiful in magit or some sort of magit+github integration (the atom plugin for reference https://github.com/philschatz/atom-pull-requests), not sure where they would best fit.

Comment: I'm hoping that our contributing to the [magit kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1681258897/its-magit-the-magical-git-client) will give a boost to this.

Comment: It surely will!

Answer (score 2):

You can get simple "manual" Github support by setting `magit-git-executable` to `"hub"`. Then you can use all `hub` commands and features through `magit-git-command` (bound to `:` in Magit buffers). This at least allows you to interact with Github through Emacs/Magit.

Although note that as of this writing, this will not work because the release version of `hub` does not recognize the `--literal-pathspecs` option , which Magit uses ([see here](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/1018)). So until the next release, you need to install hub from the latest source: https://github.com/github/hub#source

Comment: I've got this working locally (replacing the `magit-git-executable` to `"hub"`), and it does function OK with hub version 2.2.3. It has an unfortunate side effect of making every magit operation slower by at least an order of magnitude if not more.

Comment: Indeed, setting `magit-git-executable` to `"hub"` slows things down a lot. I've found a happy medium in configuring magit to only replace git with hub when running a command interactively through `magit-git-command`: https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/dotemacs/blob/master/config.org#use-hub-instead-of-git-sometimes