# Creating Pull requests right from Emacs

Tags: git, emacs, elisp, pull-request, magit

I abhore manual, tedious and repetitive tasks as any normal developer should. Recently I realized - creating pull requests on numerous git repos taking up too much of my time. And most of the time you have to follow almost exact steps over and over:

- log into git provider's web client - we use Stash
- click, click, click until you find "Create Pull Request" button, then click it
- select a branch - usually it's a branch that's just been pushed
- select a target branch - most of the time it's "develop"
- add reviewers - most of the time exact same people
- add description - optional

At some point I started wondering if I could do all that without using web client. And it seems to be possible. [Stash and Bitbucket have an api](https://bitbucket.org/aeffle/ssh-support-for-pull-request), [Github has one as well](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request) (although it is different - the first one uses ssh and the latter http)

Now, this thing would probably simplify some things, yet I feel it can be even better.

I use Emacs (Spacemacs distro, to be specific).
Now I'm wondering if anyone already built anything that integrates with `magit`, or maybe I could do it myself?
I mean how difficult would it be? 
Script should let you commit and then push the branch and then create a pull-request based of that branch against "develop", using given defaults. Has anyone done anything like that?

Can you guys point me at some `elisp` plugins that utilize power of `magit` for doing similar stuff. Maybe I'd be able to write something myself.

Comment: magit now has forge https://github.com/magit/forge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this original post on creating PRs from emacs on github.
http://endlessparentheses.com/easily-create-github-prs-from-magit.html

This didn't work for bitbucket (stash).  But it was enough information for me
to be able to hack together a solution that works for me.

https://github.com/flamingbear/emacs-config/blob/master/site-lisp/lisp/mhs-magit.el

```
(defun endless/visit-pull-request-url ()
  "Visit the current branch's PR on Github."
  (interactive)
  (let ((repo (magit-get "remote" (magit-get-remote) "url")))
    (if (string-match "github\\.com" repo)
    (visit-gh-pull-request repo)
  (visit-bb-pull-request repo))))


(defun visit-gh-pull-request (repo)
  "Visit the current branch's PR on Github."
  (interactive)
  (browse-url
   (format "https://github.com/%s/pull/new/%s"
     (replace-regexp-in-string
      "\\`.+github\\.com:\\(.+\\)\\.git\\'" "\\1"
      repo)
     (cdr (magit-get-remote-branch)))))



;; Bitbucket pull requests are kinda funky, it seems to try to just do the
;; right thing, so there's no branches to include.
;; https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<project>/pull-request/new
(defun visit-bb-pull-request (repo)
  (browse-url
   (format "https://bitbucket.org/%s/pull-request/new"
           (replace-regexp-in-string
            "\\`.+bitbucket\\.org:\\(.+\\)\\.git\\'" "\\1"
            repo))))

;; visit PR for github or bitbucket repositories with "v"
(eval-after-load 'magit
  '(define-key magit-mode-map "v"
     #'endless/visit-pull-request-url))
```

Comment: for some reason though this `(magit-get "remote" (magit-get-remote) "url")` returns `nil` for me :( I can't figure out why

Comment: Are you in a directory with a git repo and remote?  I get nil from the scratch buffer, but not from a valid repo directory.  What version of magit/emacs are you using?  `Magit 20150825.414, Git 2.3.8 (Apple Git-58), Emacs 24.5.1`

Comment: `Magit 20151001.1159, Git 2.5.3, Emacs 24.5.1` yes I am in valid git repo

Comment: I have figured. my local branch wasn't tracking the remote

Answer (score 5):

### magit forge

magit now comes with [`forge`](https://github.com/magit/forge), which is to work with issues/PR/etc. in any of the git forges. It [supports github](https://magit.vc/manual/forge/Supported-Forges-and-Hosts.html#Supported-Forges-and-Hosts), gitlab out of the box with partial support for bitbucket, gitea, gitweb, cgit, gogs etc.

To create a new pull request (or an issue) (from [the docs](https://magit.vc/manual/forge/Creating-Topics.html#Creating-Topics)):

> ```
> ' p     (forge-create-pullreq)
> ```
>
> `C-c C-n` [on "Pull requests" section]     (`forge-create-pullreq`)
>
> This command creates a new pull-request for the current repository.
>
> ```
> ' i     (forge-create-issue)
> ```
>
> `C-c C-n` [on "Issues" section]     (`forge-create-pullreq`)
>
> This command creates a new issue for the current repository.

---

### Old answer:

There is a magit extension for dealing with github pull requests. You can go through the [project here](https://github.com/sigma/magit-gh-pulls#creating-pull-requests).

You should also go through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24004744/1190388) by the magit project's maintainer.

> So I am afraid there currently isn't a package that does what you
> want. If you want to write it yourself, I recommend you use request.el
> and then only implement those parts of the Github api that you
> actually need, to avoid over-engineering it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try to play with that

Answer (score 1):

In case of `(magit-get "remote" (magit-get-remote) "url")` returns nil, has been improved.

```
(defun endless/visit-pull-request-url ()
  "Visit the current branch's PR on Github."
  (interactive)
  (let ((repo (magit-get "remote" (magit-get-remote) "url")))
    (if (not repo)
    (setq repo (magit-get "remote" (magit-get-push-remote) "url")))
    (if (string-match "github\\.com" repo)
    (visit-gh-pull-request repo)
      (visit-bb-pull-request repo))))

(defun visit-gh-pull-request (repo)
  "Visit the current branch's PR on Github."
  (interactive)
  (message repo)
  (browse-url
   (format "https://github.com/%s/pull/new/%s"
       (replace-regexp-in-string
        "\\`.+github\\.com:\\(.+\\)\\(\\.git\\)?\\'" "\\1"
        repo)
       (magit-get-current-branch))))

;; Bitbucket pull requests are kinda funky, it seems to try to just do the
;; right thing, so there's no branches to include.
;; https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<project>/pull-request/new
(defun visit-bb-pull-request (repo)
  (message repo)
  (browse-url
   (format "https://bitbucket.org/%s/pull-request/new?source=%s&t=1"
       (replace-regexp-in-string
        "\\`.+bitbucket\\.org:\\(.+\\)\\.git\\'" "\\1"
        repo)
       (magit-get-current-branch))))
;; visit PR for github or bitbucket repositories with "v"
(eval-after-load 'magit
  '(define-key magit-mode-map "v"
     #'endless/visit-pull-request-url))
```